# trying to create a population of genomes

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I've been working on implementing a genetic algorithm, and I'm currently trying to use my initialize population function to create a population of 100 genomes. But I keep getting the following error

> AttributeError: type object 'genomes' has no attribute
>   'initalize_population'

So far I have, at least what I think I have is, assigned genomes

```
class genomes:
    def __init__(self, genetics):
        genomes = self.genetics.inital()
```

and an `initialize_population` function

```
def initalize_population(input_node, output_nodes, activation):
    return genomes
    while genomes <= 100:
        genomes.append(genomes(input_node, output_nodes, activation))
```

and here's the line where my code breaks down

```
genomes.initalize_population(input_node, output_nodes, activation)
```

my full code is here...

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random

#activation functions
def softmax(x):

    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)

def relu(x):

    return max(0, x)

#configurations
input_node=(32, 32, 3)
input_nodes = 60000
hidden_nodes = 1
output_nodes = 10
edges = input_nodes * hidden_nodes + hidden_nodes * output_nodes
input_filter_size = (3, 3)
output_filter_size = (3, 3)
input_depth = 3
output_depth = 3
options = {'o': [(-2, -2), (-1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 2)]}
selected = random.choice(options['o'])
filter_size = (selected[0] + input_filter_size[0], selected[1] + input_filter_size[1])
num_nodes = random.randrange(1, 30000)
layers = num_nodes, filter_size
activation = softmax

#hyperparameters
b = 3
alpha = 0.001
momentum = 0.9
decay = 0.997
threshold_value = 1
MFP_rate = 0.25
LFP_rate = 0.15

class genomes:
    def __init__(self, genetics):
        genomes = self.genetics.inital()
        #return genomes

def initalize_population(input_node, output_nodes, activation):
    return genomes
    while genomes <= 100:
        genomes.append(genomes(input_node, output_nodes, activation))

genomes.initalize_population(input_node, output_nodes, activation)
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: class method `initalize_population` is not properly indented.  You need to indent it the same way method `__init__` is indented.

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but method `initalize_population` has `return genomes` as it's first line.  This will keep it from entering the while loop.  Also why is genomes used for the name of class and instance variables?  Overusing it this way makes the code confusing.

Comment: fixing the indentation did get rid of the error, but when I took out ```return genomes``` I got  ```TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'``` which would of been here ```while genomes <= 100:```

Comment: @spe301--it's a bit confusing on your use of genomes.  Is there a reason its used for the class name and variable instance?  I assume the line is referring to the instance variable genomes which would be self.genomes.  But, since you didn't instantiate a class there is no instance variable (i.e. no object).  Also, since initalize_population is a class method (rather than instance method) it can't refer to instance variables.